# Difference in behavior when assigning to variables which share names with properties of window object in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

Attempting to assign values to properties of the window object in Microsoft Edge fails, which differs from the behavior in firefox and chrome.

- Going forward, will I need to keep each property of the window object in mind when naming variables? Are there any tools to help with this?
- If a future edge release adds a new property to the window object, will that break the existing code?
- While I have confirmed this behavior for the window object, are there other global names that have this behavior?

While in the case where this is an issue for me, I was simply able to change the name of my variable to return the code to working order, this doesn't seem like a long term solution.

```js
// First example
const foo = { control: 123, focus: 456, alert: 789 };
const { control, focus, alert } = foo;

console.log(control, focus, alert);

console.log(focus === window.focus);
console.log(alert === window.alert);

// Second example
const unescape = 'test';
console.log(unescape);
```

Regarding the first example:

The first console.log prints `123`, `456`, `789` in firefox and chrome. Edge prints the control correctly, but returns functions for the other two parameters.

The later two logs each print `false` in firefox and chrome, while printing `true` in Edge.

---

Regarding the second example:

Please note that I have this simpler example listed second because I only tested it in the browser's console, whereas the first I noted in actively running code.

In firefox and chrome, the value `'test'` is stored in `unescape`.  It is successfully printed in the following line.

In edge attempting to assign to `unescape` produces an `Unspecified Error`.

Comment: edge is moving to V8 soon, so keep that in mind when thinking about the future. More generally, you should not shadow BOM properties and methods, for maximum backwards compat. In IE, `typeof alert` was _Object_, so they have always been a bit special. You can use modules if you _need_ a particular name in your code for some reason.

Comment: Your code logs the same results for me in Edge as in Firefox or Chrome...

Comment: I can't replicate the behavior your'e describing in Edge 44.18362.387.0. Please update your answer with the full HTML of a page you're using to test, so people can copy-and-paste to try *exactly* what you're doing for themselves

Comment: *"Attempting to assign values to properties of the window object in edge..."* Note that you **aren't** assigning values to properties of the window object in that code. You're assigning values to your own `const` identifiers, which are *separate* from window properties. `const`, `let`, and `class` identifiers at global scope don't create properties on `window` like `var` and `function` do. That's one of the key differences of the new declarations.

Comment: Just double-checked, and v44.18362.387.0 is the latest Windows 10 version of Edge.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or an answer), please *stick around* so you can respond to anything that comes up in the comments.

Comment: I tried to test the issue with Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 and I found that it returns the correct results like other browsers. https://i.postimg.cc/2yFTcBXG/316.png Can you please inform us which exact version of Edge browser you are using for making test? If you are using any older version then you can try to install the latest version and make a test with it to check the results.